# C#: How to store stuff in dynamic arrays?

Tags: c#

I am writing a program where the users can type any number and amount of denomination + one overall input. The program has to get this input and store them somewhere to be able to use them for further usage such as calculations.
Could you please tell me how to define this first part and how to access the stored info?

Comment: You want a `List` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This has nothing to do with dynamic arrays, you know the input types you are going to receive, do some research on what kind of array/collection suits you best to store this data, and come back when you find specific issues related to your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal to use an Array for any dynamic data.

```
//You can add to a list dynamically
List<int> denominations = new List<int>();

//Values below are hardcoded for demonstration purposes
denominations.Add(34);
denominations.Add(12);
denominations.Add(95);

//Iterate over list
foreach (int item in denominations)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: The thing is the denominations must be typed by the user. you have to fetch them later and store them somewhere to use them. How  can I do these two tasks?

Comment: What do you mean by later? Are we talking mins, hours, days? Also, what kind of application is this for (Web, Desktop, Console, etc...)?